# How to make 2 div tags next to each other

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to put these 2 divs next to each other. State and ZipCode. I understand that that div is block element but I am setting the inline-block property in the css. That is also attached. How can I go about having State and Zipcode next to each other? I been trying different things and am frustrated with it. Any help appreciated!! Thanks :)

```css
.dataControl {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.dataControlSmall {
  width: 25%;
}
.dataControl45 {
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataControl dataControlSmall">
  <div class="dataControl dataControl45" style="float: left; display: block;">
    <label for="txtState" style="display: block;">State</label>
    <input id="txtState" name="txtState" class="k-textbox" style="width:35px; display: block;" maxlength="2" required="required" data-bind="value: State" />
  </div>
  <div class="dataControl dataControl45" style="float: left; display: block;">
    <label for="txtZip" style="display: block;">Zip Code</label>
    <input id="txtZip" name="txtZip" class="k-textbox" style="width:90px; display: block;" maxlength="10" required="required" data-bind="value: Zip" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the inline-block and the float will take effect

Answer (score 1):

Once you set `display:inline-block` just make sure that the total width of the two elements or element in them is less or equal to `100%` of their parent. If the combined width of both is greater than the width of the parent, the second will show on the next line.

```css
.dataControl {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.dataControlSmall {
  width: 100%;
}
.dataControl45 {
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataControl dataControlSmall">
  <div class="dataControl dataControl45" style="float: left; display: block;">
    <label for="txtState" style="display: block;">State</label>
    <input id="txtState" name="txtState" class="k-textbox" style="width:35px; display: block;" maxlength="2" required="required" data-bind="value: State" />
  </div>
  <div class="dataControl dataControl45" style="float: left; display: block;">
    <label for="txtZip" style="display: block;">Zip Code</label>
    <input id="txtZip" name="txtZip" class="k-textbox" style="width:90px; display: block;" maxlength="10" required="required" data-bind="value: Zip" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the parent div.

```
<div class="dataControl dataControlSmall" style="width:100%">
```

You may also want to set width on the children divs as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ppLw8ypw/)

You set a very high right margin for `.dataControl` which was pushing it.

Reduce the margin values and the two divs will be aligned side by side. So, the new CSS for `.dataControl` would be as below

```
.dataControl {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px 3px;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: This is somewhere close to what I want it to be Lal. How do I decrease the space between State and ZipCode?

Answer (score 0):

The inline CSS `style="float:left;display:block;"` overrides your internal/external css setting it to `display:inline-block;`. Use one or the other; I would recommend not using the inline style.

It may help seeing the whole page but if the `.dataControlSmall` is 30% of a set width the input fields my be too large to stack next to each other, especially since an exact width is declared (`width:35px;` & `width:90px;`).

If you can, I would wrap the input field with the label, and remove the size declaration of the input field. Handle your CSS in one spot if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

**CSS**

```
.dataControl {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.dataControlSmall {
  width: 30px;
}
.dataControl45 {
  width: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

You do not need use `dataControlSmall` class in outer `div` because if you include it in outer div, characteristic of `dataControlSmall` will be included.

```
<div class="dataControl">
  <div class="dataControl dataControlSmall" style="float: left; display: block;">
    <label for="txtState" style="display: block;">State</label>
    <input id="txtState" name="txtState" class="k-textbox" style="width:35px; display: block;" maxlength="2" required="required" data-bind="value: State" />
  </div>
  <div class="dataControl dataControl45" style="float: left; display: block;">
    <label for="txtZip" style="display: block;">Zip Code</label>
    <input id="txtZip" name="txtZip" class="k-textbox" style="width:90px; display: block;" maxlength="10" required="required" data-bind="value: Zip" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. i just newbie and i still need more advices.